# warning: Corrupted shared library list

Tags: linux, gcc, g++, shared-libraries

Under linux, when debugging my program with gdb the following message appears:

```
warning: Corrupted shared library list: 0x639130 != 0x7ffff7fd9598
```

In my program I am loading several .so files via dlopen(). After calling dlopen(), the message appears.

Then, when I load the next .so, the message appears again, but this time with different addresses:

```
warning: Corrupted shared library list: 0x63c9e0 != 0x639130
```

I have looked for references about this message on the internet but have not found anything. There are some references about a corrupted shared library, but not about a corrupted shared library list.

Does anyone know what might be the cause for this?

I am running Ubuntu AMD64 and compile in 64bit with g++ command line options:

```
-std=c++11 -fPIC
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
You need to make a reproducible example.

Comment: I can't. The problem only appears when I use my own libraries and excutables. 
I tried creating just a very simple executable which loads another very simple .so and the warning does not appear.

Comment: Perhaps this?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30128220/finding-cause-of-corrupted-shared-library-error-qt5-c

Comment: I think this is coming from Qt code.

Comment: @WilliamKF I see this when making use of reverse-execution *(while debugging a Qt app)*, however it is absent before that while recording the program execution through `rr record`. Since there shouldn't appear any new stdout/stderr once execution is recorded, I'm inclined to think the message comes from gdb, not Qt.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be occurring when one of the shared library dlopen()ed by the program also has code to dlopen() a library that has already been loaded previously.